# Memory mapping in block IO device in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, memory-mapping, block-device

I was going through device driver development in Linux. I've come across memory mapping of device driver in Linux.

I was trying to develop a RAM Disk block device driver (which creates virtual disk out of RAM). But I coudln't figure out how to use memory mapping here (just for trying out).

I guess block devices would 've used memory mapping.

Can someone shed some light on this ?

Also, if we map the memory in user space using remap_pfn_range, how will that work ? If the user simply writes something on the region, will it get automatically reflected inside the device or the request function that got registered for I/O will be called ?

Comment: did you visit this link ?.Thought it might be helpful.
http://www.scs.ch/~frey/linux/memorymap.html

Comment: Hi @user1585811, that material gives an example about character device. But my question was about block devices.

Comment: Linux already has a ram disk driver, `drivers/block/brd.c`, I suggest you read it and see if you can understand how it works.